# Set document mode

Tags: xpages, lotus, lotus-domino

I have a view on a Xpage called Main.xsp which needs to open documents in read mode on a different xpage called Contact.xsp. I get the documents to open as they should, since it's very simple and basic. But somehow the SetDocumentMode doesn't work!?
I have a button, when clicked it should set the document mode to Edit. I've tried using the simple actions from the menu, i've tried all of the examples here http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_documents_and_fields_on_the_XPage#Check+for+edit+mode+and+set+edit+mode
What the hell am i doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Also, even though the url is docID&action=editDocument the document is not editable.

EDIT

This is weird... I was triple-checking my ACL. And tried changing Anonymous access to Editor, and now it works!? I switch it back to Author with all the available options checked and it doesn't work!?

Is this some kind of bug?

Comment: Does the document contain reader/author fields?

Comment: Thanks for replying, and no it doesn't. Since you mentioned that, I also have Author rights to Anonymous in ACL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Author rights for Anonymous does give Anonymous the ability to create a document (if that box is ticked) - but NOT the ability to EDIT any document. UNLESS you have a field of type Author that has "Anonymous" as one value (or a role that you assigned to Anonymous".

The definition of AUTHOR access:

- Can create documents (if "create documents" is checked)
- can edit any document where an AUTHOR field contains the user's name, a group or role (s)he is member of.

Explanation here: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-89PMVR
(and basics before here: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-89N7XR )

Comment: This line - "While they have no problems with "the other skills", all things Domino are new to them." Very true. Thank you good sir :)

Comment: Definitely what the problem is, however it is confusing, To me if you don't have access to switch the document mode an Exception should be thrown as you are trying to do something you don't have access to.

Comment: Thats's a interesting ongoing discussion. Throw an error or gracefully degrade? A door doesn't throw an error if you don't have a matching key. Also in this case it makes your life easier: Open the document in edit mode if the user can edit otherwise go read mode... without you doing if/else code

Comment: sorry I forgot, but it's accepted now :) I also think that it shouldn't throw an error, because than as stwissel said, you'd have to write code by yourself to avoid that... All one should do is, read some documentation I guess :)